# Serialize model with only properties I want

Tags: c#, serialization

I have two models in my MVC4 application defined like this:

```
public class Attendee
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public Info _Info { get; set; }
}
public class Info
{
    public string License { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Declined { get; set; }
}
```

I need to also be able to totally remove the Info from an Attendee object before it is converted to JSON.

Or should I create another model without it and somehow transfer the values from one to the other?

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like what your real question is: *how do I serialize only the properties I want*.  Is that essentially your question?

Comment: Sounds like the correct question but I'm building a more in depth model that contains an array of Attendee objects and I need to remove the Info from each of them. The data contained in the Info  is sent to my controller inside the Attendee so I need to remove it after I move the Info data to another part of my larger model.

Comment: Be careful how you word your question.  It's very possible to go down the wrong path and create an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  There are ways to serialize objects without specific properties on the object being serialized.  Therefore removing the *info from an attendee* is not really an issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily you don't have circular reference in your model, so you can put `[JsonIgnore]` on any properties which you don't want in json format:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public Info _Info { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON classes. Will this work with them?

Comment: [JsonIgnoreAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) is Newtonsoft specific.

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft but it says that `[JsonIgnoreAttribute]` could not be found

Comment: My Bad... need to use `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: @Cuong Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/qiOdmT